# cvGetSubRect doesn't put in frame

Tags: python, opencv

I am new in working with OpenCV face detector. Face detection works fine but I am trying to use the rectangle generated to make a frame arround the face and cut it to save the face in a new archive. I have been using getSubRect with the values returned by "haarcascade_frontalface_default" (left, upper, width, height). It is supposed that the that the parameteres of GetSubRect are (image, (left, upper, right, bottom) but it doesn't work because resulting image doesn't get the face centered. What is my mistake?

The code is the next:

```
import sys
   import cv
   imcolor = cv.LoadImage('C:\\Temp\\camera_test2.jpg') # input image
   # loading the classifier
   haarFace = cv.Load('c:\opencv\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
   # running the classifier
   storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
   detectedFace = cv.HaarDetectObjects(imcolor, haarFace, storage, 1.1)
   if detectedFace:
     arg1 = detectedFace[0][0][0]
     arg2 = detectedFace[0][0][1]
     arg3 = detectedFace[0][0][2]
     arg4 = detectedFace[0][0][3]
     Izq = arg1 - arg3/10
     Sup = arg2 - arg4/6
     Der = arg1 + arg3 #+ (arg3/10)
     Inf = arg2 + arg4 +(arg4/6)
     print detectedFace
     print Izq
     print Sup
     print Der
     print Inf
   imcolor2 = cv.GetSubRect(imcolor,(Izq, Sup, Der, Inf))
   cv.SaveImage('C:\\temp\\test_1.JPG', imcolor2)
   cv.WaitKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv.GetSubRect` expects `(x, y, width, height)`:

```
for face, neighbors in detectedFace:
    im_face = cv.GetSubRect(imcolor, face)
```

Also see the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/objdetect_cascade_classification.html#haardetectobjects) and the [OpenCV Cookbook](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#using-getsubrect).

That said, why don't you use `cv2`?

Comment: `cv2` represents OpenCV v2 and includes v1 as `cv2.cv`.
There is [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) for the successor of `HaarDetectObjects` and a [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) in C++. (in python it works the same)

Comment: Yes Malthaeus, I made the changes and worked fine. The only problem is that opencv can't work as an web application. Thank you.